# Sql Query for get Summarize values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an sample table to  find number of loans for every month in each Branch by each User, using sql server, how can I do this

```
LoanID  User    Amount  Branch  Date 
001     KevinU  215000  SDC     07/9/2014 4:18:52PM
005     DenisM  520000  CVD     06/12/2014 4:18:52PM
004     KelumK  1200000 BBV     06/12/2014 4:18:52PM
002     KevinU  100000  SDC     12/9/2014 4:18:52PM
```

output should like

```
User    NoOfLoans   Branch  Month
KevinU  2           SDC     201409
```

Comment: what is the logic behind `month : 20149`?

Comment: `month : 20149` is that year and month ?

Comment: yes month key like  -  SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(6), GETDATE(), 112)

Comment: need to convert date to month key

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your using MSSQL, See the sql query below:

`select user,count(loanID),branch,DATEPART(month, Date) from table_name group by user,branch,DATEPART(month, Date)`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  User,
        Count(LoanID) as NoOfLoans,
        Branch,
        concat(DATEPART(YEAR, Date), DATEPART(MONTH, Date))
FROM    MyTable
GROUP BY User, Branch,DATEPART(YEAR, Date), DATEPART(MONTH, Date);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this for your Result:

```
select User,count(loanID) as NoOfLoans,Branch,concat(year(Date),month(Date))
as Month from sample_table group by  User,Branch,concat(year(Date),month(Date))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
SELECT
    [User],
    [Branch],
    [Month] = CAST(YEAR([DATE]) AS VARCHAR(5))+CAST(MONTH([DATE]) AS VARCHAR(5)),
    Loans = COUNT(1)
    FROM YourTable 
        GROUP BY [User],
    [Branch],CAST(YEAR([DATE]) AS VARCHAR(5)),CAST(MONTH([DATE]) AS VARCHAR(5))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT USER,
       COUNT(*)OVER(PARTITION BY Name,Branch,Month(Date) order by Branch,Month(Date)) AS NoOfLoans,
       Branch,
       CONCAT(Year(DATE),Month(Date)) AS YearMonth FROM Table_Name 
       --WHERE USER=001
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  User,  Count(LoanID) as NoOfLoans,
Branch,DATEPART(year,date) +DATEPART(month,date) as month
FROM  Table
GROUP BY User, Branch , DATEPART(year,date) ,DATEPART(month,date)
```